# save rtsp h264 stream with Jcodec (on Android)

Tags: android, streaming, h.264, rtsp

Did anyone manage to save a rtsp video stream (h264 mpeg) using [Jcodec](https://github.com/jcodec/jcodec)?

Could you please give me an example?

Also any other method of saving a rtsp stream on an android device would be of great help.

Please don't include any solution that requires device specific compilation ( ffmpeg, by example, is not ok, because it needs to be compiled for the specific arm version).
So I need a pure java solution, if not Jcodec.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem!
I'm using ffmpeg on my server and save all video.

Next I save the video on the device calling it to server.

Comment: thank you for your answer, buy adding a server isn't a viable choice for me.